# Save blob wav file on Server with getUserMedia and XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: xmlhttprequest, wav, getusermedia

I'm trying to save the resulting wav file from a microphone recording with getUserMedia, I am using the script from Matt Diamond, Recorder.js, but in my main file, when i get the file blod ready to send with XMLHttpRequest (), through to save the file with  POST in saveWav.php, are files empty wav without the audio recording with Recorder.js. May be due to this?

The files are:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Live input record and playback</title>
  <style type='text/css'>
    ul { list-style: none; }
    #recordingslist audio { display: block; margin-bottom: 10px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Recorder.js simple WAV export example</h1>

  <p>Make sure you are using a recent version of Google Chrome, at the moment this only works with Google Chrome Canary.</p>
  <p>Also before you enable microphone input either plug in headphones or turn the volume down if you want to avoid ear splitting feedback!</p>

  <button onclick="startRecording(this);">record</button>
  <button onclick="stopRecording(this);" disabled>stop</button>

  <h2>Recordings</h2>
  <ul id="recordingslist"></ul>

  <h2>Log</h2>
  <pre id="log"></pre>

  <script>
  function __log(e, data) {
    log.innerHTML += "\n" + e + " " + (data || '');
  }

  var audio_context;
  var recorder;

  function startUserMedia(stream) {
    var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    __log('Media stream created.');

    input.connect(audio_context.destination);
    __log('Input connected to audio context destination.');

    recorder = new Recorder(input);
    __log('Recorder initialised.');
  }

  function startRecording(button) {
    recorder && recorder.record();
    button.disabled = true;
    button.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
    __log('Recording...');
  }

  function stopRecording(button) {
    recorder && recorder.stop();
    button.disabled = true;
    button.previousElementSibling.disabled = false;
    __log('Stopped recording.');

    // create WAV download link using audio data blob
    createDownloadLink();

    recorder.clear();
  }

  function createDownloadLink() {
    recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
      var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      var au = document.createElement('audio');
      var hf = document.createElement('a');
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.open('POST', 'saveWav.php', true);
      xhr.onload = function (e) {
          var result = e.target.result;
      };
      xhr.send(url);//url is Blob

      au.controls = true;
      au.src = url;
      hf.href = url;
      hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
      hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
      li.appendChild(au);
      li.appendChild(hf);
      recordingslist.appendChild(li);
    });
  }

  window.onload = function init() {
    try {
      // webkit shim
      window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
      navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
      window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

      audio_context = new AudioContext;
      __log('Audio context set up.');
      __log('navigator.getUserMedia ' + (navigator.getUserMedia ? 'available.' : 'not present!'));
    } catch (e) {
      alert('No web audio support in this browser!');
    }

    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia, function(e) {
      __log('No live audio input: ' + e);
    });
  };
  </script>

  <script src="recorder.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And file saveWav.php:

```
<?php
   if( isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA))
   {
      $cad = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
      $date = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
      $stringas = explode(":",$cad);
      $type = explode(";", $stringas[1]);
      $base = explode(",", $type[1]);
      $base64 = $base[1];
      print_r ( $base64 );

      $myFile = "grabacion.".$date.".wav";
      $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
      fwrite($fh, base64_decode($base64));
   }
?>
```

Thank you very much for your help! 
Greetings

Comment: did you get any solution, am stuck in same problem